# How to update the OAuth Broker version on Keboola?

Tags: facebook, components, ads

I am trying to connect component for Facebook Ads on Keboola. I log in successfully and choose the account, but once I run the job, I get "OAuth Broker v2 has been deprecated on September 30, 2019. [https://status.keboola.com/end-of-life-old-oauth-broker"](https://status.keboola.com/end-of-life-old-oauth-broker%22) error. How do I update the OAuth Broker?

I also tried to use the access token from Marketing API app on FB, but this gives me another error - missing ID, that cannot be added anywhere and it won't let me authorize.

How can I authorize the component? Or how can I update the OAuth Broker version?